# 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, community, js-controller

I am getting below error in lightning JS controller on `enqueueAction`.

> TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them
>   
>     at Function.remoteFunction (:2:14)
>   
>     at validateData

I'm calling server side method to insert record in object, this object has one encrypted field, I am inserting value in that field as well.

Record gets created in object but on `setCallBack` I'm getting this error.

Comment: Can you include your actual code?

Comment: @DavidReed I can't include my code here.

Comment: @DavidReed I'm sorry for not including my  code here.
I have written a aura enabled method with sObject parameter to insert a record in custom object and on setParam in JS controller, I'm passing the sObject to method. I have declared aura:attribute with type sObject with required fields. one field on object is encrypted, i am insert value in that field as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is resolved.
Thank you all for all you pointers.
we have anchor tag for save button which has hRef parameter set to "#" which us causign this issue.
We removed it to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Are you accidentally using the name `arguments` in your JavaScript code? If so use a different name e.g. `args` as `arguments` in JavaScript [represents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments):

> The arguments object is an Array-like object corresponding to the
>   arguments passed to a function

If you are intentionally using it then the bottom line is that you can't as its use is blocked in Lightning Components.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I havent used 'arguments'  in my code.

Comment: @ManojPatil Are you using any 3rd party or local JavaScript libraries?

Comment: yes,  I'm using jquery v3.3.1.

Comment: @ManojPatil AFAIK that version works in Lightning Components but as I never use it there I may be wrong. Or the problem may be something else entirely.

Comment: @ManojPatil Also worth searching for `caller` or `callee` in your JavaScript, though less likely so causer a problem.